# How to use OrderBy in Doctrine with findBY function

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

When I am using this function:

```
$TopItemList = $app['orm.em']->getRepository('\Eccube\Entity\Product')
->findBy(array('name' => array('booktest1', 'booktest2', 'booktest3')));
```

But I want the results in 'name' order by: **'booktest1', 'booktest2', 'booktest3'** because now order is **'booktest3', 'booktest1', 'booktest2'**.

I don't know how to use **"orderby"**.

Comment: Help us help you by providing a [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You want to have your results ordered by `name` field?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the way to order your entities

```
$TopItemList = $app['orm.em']
    ->getRepository('\Eccube\Entity\Product')
        ->findBy(
            array('name'), 
            array(
                'booktest1' => 'ASC',
                'booktest2' => 'ASC',
                'booktest3' => 'ASC'
            )
        );
```

Comment: thx your answer $TopItemList = $app['orm.em']->getRepository('\Eccube\Entity\Product') ->findBy(array('name' => array('booktest1', 'booktest2', 'booktest3'))); it can work but your code cant work now i want to get the order of booktest 1 2 3 but in webpage it show me 3 1 2 i dont know why. maybe is ASC problem

Answer (score 0):

As @sdespont said, order is passed as a second argument of findBy method.

Everything is in [doctrine docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-simple-conditions):

> The EntityRepository#findBy() method additionally accepts orderings,
>   limit and offset as second to fourth parameters:
>
> ```
> <?php $tenUsers =
> $em->getRepository('MyProject\Domain\User')->findBy(array('age' =>
> 20), array('name' => 'ASC'), 10, 0);
> ```

Comment: thx your answer       $TopItemList = $app['orm.em']->getRepository('\Eccube\Entity\Product')
->findBy(array('name' => array('booktest1', 'booktest2', 'booktest3')));  it can work but i want to kave the order of booktest 1 2 3 but in webpage it show me 3 1 2 i dont know why. maybe is ASC problem

Comment: $TopItemList = $app['orm.em']->getRepository('\Eccube\Entity\Product') ->findBy(
    ['name' => ['booktest1', 'booktest2', 'booktest3']], 
    ['name' => 'ASC']
);
You're sure it's not working as intended?

Comment: if i want to get the order of booktest 2 1 3 cant use ASC or DESC ,HOW to do it ? thx u